# PHP - How to find user level based on their username?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I need to find a way to get the user level off of the user's username. My username variable is: 
`$username = $_SESSION['username'];`
I already have all the user levels stored in the database in the table 'users' and column 'level'. I need a MySql query that will allow me to make a session variable like so:
`$_SESSION['level'] =`
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you post some more code, I and clexmond (SO too) can help you more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT level FROM users WHERE username = 'username';
```

Then depending on what you're using to access the DB (PDO, etc.) grab the level and plunk it into the session.

For example, if you're using PDO:

```
# Connect to the database
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

$sql    = 'SELECT level FROM users WHERE username = :username';
$query  = $db->prepare($sql); # Prepare SQL statement to prevent SQL Injection Attack
$query->execute(array(':username' => $username)); # Bind parameter username
$_SESSION['level'] = $query->getColumn(); # Fetch data & Assign to session variable
```

Check out http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php for more information on using PDO.

Note: if you are using a function to fetch data, and your $db connection statement is outside of that function, that means your $db variable is outside of the scope of the function so it will not work. You will need to use the `global` keyword to fix this. Example:

```
# database.php
$db = new PDO(...);

# otherfile.php
require_once("database.php");
function makeQuery($sql, $dataArr) {
    global $db; # tell the compiler we mean the $db object above
    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute($dataArr);
}
```

Comment: How would I put that into a mysql query? (I'm new at PHP and MySQL). I tried this but it didn't work. `$qry="SELECT level FROM users WHERE username = '$username';"; 
    $result=mysql_query($qry); 
    echo "$result";`

Comment: mysql_query is the wrong way to go. It will soon be deprecated and it has a lot of security issues that are taken care of by using something like PDO. Check out what I added to my answer.

Comment: `echo $result` will be `true` or `false` only (0/1, etc) because you are echoing if query executed.

Comment: I see. Than how would I echo the actual user level using this code? `$qry="SELECT level FROM users WHERE username = '$username';"; $result=mysql_query($qry); echo "$result";`

Comment: If you really want to go that route despite future deprecation and security concerns: `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); $level = $row['level'];`

Answer (score 0):

i suggest storing level as session variable at the time when you are storing username as session variable may be when the user is signing in

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE user = '$user' AND pass = '$pass'";
$result=mysql_query($sql); 
$user = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
$_SESSION['user'] = $user['user']; 
$_SESSION['level'] = $user['level'];
```

this way you dont have to query every time for user's level you can call its level anytime using $_SESSION['level']